# How to get an incremented value to keep its count

Tags: c#

The way my code is currently written, it will change the name of a file to the current date and then it will move it to a completed folder in the sub directory. That all works fine.

What I'm trying to implement is being able to rename it with different numbers as well if there are duplicates. Basically, if the file already exists in the completed folder, it will rename it "the date"(1).csv.

My issue is that because i is set to 1, even though I increment i, it resets it back to 1. I just want it to hold the incremented value while the code is running. if there are three files in the folder it retrieves it from, I want it to label them "the date", "the date"(1), and "the date"(2). Then if the code runs again tomorrow it will start the count over. Most likely my code will never experience more than one file in the folder. I want to implement this as a safety. If for whatever reason there is more than one file in the folder I want my code to be able to still run.

This is what I have so far:

```
int i = 1;
var newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".csv";
destinationPath = Path.Combine(GenesisDirectory, "Completed");
Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
var destinationFileName = Path.GetFileName(newFileName);

destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName);

if (File.Exists(destinationPath))
{
     newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "(" + i + ")" + ".csv";
     destinationFileName = Path.GetFileName(newFileName);
     var Dironly = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath);
     destinationPath = Path.Combine(Dironly, destinationFileName);
     i++;
}

File.Move(inputFile, destinationPath);
```

Comment: How is `i` being reset to `1`?  If you're running this code more than once, then you're declaring a new `int i = 1;` every time.  Move the variable to a different scope maybe?

Comment: You need to store that counter somewhere.

Comment: I would just like to say that your current approach is absolutely fine. It will work every time, and if it's only run a couple of times per day, the slightly reduced performace won't matter.

Comment: @Sphinxxx actually the code is not fine. What happens if the file gets created between the call to File.Exists and File.Move? The code is not atomic so it has TOCTOU issues.

Comment: @dman2306 Sure, if this code is run from multiple threads, and race conditions are an issue, you'll need a little more work. For example, put one `lock` around the `File` operations, using a static lock object.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Not just threads. It can be a single threaded app. A lock won't help. The file system is a shared resource. What if I open notepad and create a file with the name `06162016 (1).csv` after the `File.Exists` but before the `File.Move`? It doesn't have anything to do with his app, it has to do with the fact that Windows is a multitasking OS.

Comment: I wouldn't keep a counter. That doesn't handle if something external to your app created a file. Just do a loop right there and check if MMDDYYYY (N).csv exists. If it doesn't, that's the one to use

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make your counter static so it persists across calls. You will need to move it out of any method it is in to do that. There are better ways to do it, but you've somewhat limited the scope of solutions by not providing more of your code.

Comment: This piece of code is part of a much larger function that parses csv data and uploads that data into a SQL server. I didn't want to overload my question with too much code. This is the only code relevant to my question. This is inside of another static function

Comment: @user6451557 You don't have to show everything, but having the class/method name makes it easier to refer to things in conversations.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int s_Counter = 1;

public static IncrementCounter () { Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Counter); }

public static int Counter { get { return s_Counter; } }
```

We use `Interlocked.Increment` instead of `s_Counter += 1` in case you later decide to make your code multi-threaded. (As a rule, static methods/properties should be designed to be thread safe.)

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it as static to make the value persist across the call,but the counter value will reset if you restart your application that will result in some undesirable behaviour.
The best practice is to store your counter value in a database or a file so that even after restarting your application you can access the updated counter value and your code will correctly.